# Update shopping cart quantity PHP

Tags: php, cart

I'm building a test shopping site using PHP / mySQL

here is my code:

the show_product.php:

```
<form method ="get" action="addtocart.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value='.$row['id_product'].'>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"><a href="#">'.$row['name'].'</a></th>
                    </tr>                     
                        <td>
                        <a href="#"><img align="center"  src='.$row['photo'].' alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>'.mb_substr($row['description'],0,200).'....</td>                                                 
                    <tr></tr>                           
                        <td>
                        '.$row['price'].'€<input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="20">
                    </td>

                    <td> <button type="submit" class="btn">add to cart</button></form>
```

the addtocart.php

```
session_start()
if(isset($_GET) & !empty($_GET)){   
    $id_product = $_GET['id_product'];
    if(isset($_GET['quantity']) & !empty($_GET['quantity'])){ $quant = $_GET['quantity']; }else{ $quant = 1;}
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id_product] = array("quantity" => $quant);   
    header('location: cart.php');
}else{

    header('location: cart.php');
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

and some code of the cart.php

```
    foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
                    $cartsql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_product=$key";
                    $cartres = mysqli_query($con, $cartsql);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartres);    
             ?>
                <tr><form>
                   <td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['price'].' €'; ?></td>
                   **<td><input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $value['quantity']; ?>"></td>**         
                    <td><?php echo ($row['price']*$value['quantity']).' €'; ?> </td>
                    <td><a href="delcart.php?id_product=<?php echo $key; ?>"><img width="30" height="30" src="icons/delete.png" alt=""></a></td> </tr>
```

If i send to addcart  an item of some quantity it's working.

the problem is I cannot change the quantity inside on cart.php, I know very few about Javascript. 
Please any help how to  do this ??

Comment: I saw you had an answer to what you're working on, but I would mention looking into things like SQL injection and sanitizing strings users have access to (such as getting data from the $_GET array). Your code looks open to these types of attacks and it's worth knowing the security risks, especially working with PHP. I would strongly suggest using prepared statements for your sql calls (https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you're not planning on using some sort of ORM like Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

i did it with a submit form inside the cart :)

```
<form class="userform" method='get' name="change" action="addtocart.php">
                        <input type='hidden' name='id_product' value="<?php echo $row["id_product"]; ?>" />
                        <td><input size="5" type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $value['quantity'] ?>" min="1" max="20" onchange="this.form.submit()"></td></form>
```